# dynamic html editing

Tags: php

I have two html pages;

The first page has two input text boxes and a submit button. Text box A is for inputting an image URL and Text box B is for inputting a link URL.

The second page has an dummy image linked to a dummy URL.

Upon entering an image URL into the first text box and a link URL into the second text box and clicking the submit button, I want the image on the second page to become the one specified by the image URL, hyperlinked to the link URL (ie the image clickable and linked to the link URL).

Can this be done ?

Comment: Yes it can be done, but you won't get any meaningful answers unless you tell us how you plan to store the url's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite straightforward in PHP.

Assuming:

- the form on the first page uses the GET method
- textbox A is named 'imageUrl'
- textbox B is named 'linkUrl'

you can output a link using the image as the link content as follows:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_GET['linkUrl'] ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $_GET['imageUrl'] ?>" />
</a>
```